# How do I push new code to an existing repo? (as a new branch)

Tags: git, gitlab

- I have an existing repo in gitlab with multiple branches
- I did some work outside of that repo which I didn't mean to be part of it
- I changed my mind and I want to push the new code, which is not a git repository, as a new branch of the existing repo

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's a bit vague but something like this should work (using Bash):

1. Create a new branch in your existing repo

   ```
   git checkout -b $new_branch
   ```
2. Copy/move the new code into the repo

   ```
   cp $new_code .
   ```
3. Commit and push

   ```
   git commit -am "Create $new_branch from external work in $new_code"
   git push -u origin $new_branch
   ```